# I want to get the exact match using grep

Tags: shell, grep

```
grep -w STATUS pin_db_alert.conf
```

The output is:

```
abc@STATUS
abc@STATUS
@STATUS
```

I want only `@status` in output.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use below command to get @STATUS in your output

```
grep -o @STATUS pin_db_alert.conf
```

Comment: This will print `@STATUS` once for each match (in this case, 3 times).

Comment: yes becuase _@STATUS_ is present at 3 locations in line. **grep -o -w @STATUS pin_db_alert.conf** this will print _@STATUS@_ only once if you want it like that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot please see the above comment for your concern.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
grep -w "STATUS" pin_db_alert.conf | awk '{print $3}'
```

Use `awk` to print `@STATUS` alone.